# Jquery smooth scroll with offset

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have the following code for smooth scroll on my website. Right now when I click to move to a new section it is cutting off the title of the section. I have seen other jquery examples showing offset, but I would like to modify this code as it is working no my site now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function (event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            $("html, body").animate(
                {
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top,
                },
                800,
                function () {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add your HTML code too

Comment: @Yushan I don't have access to the base code (it's through a template service), but my website is here. ercspecialists.com

Answer (score 1):

When you set a section's top to `scrollTop`, it will scroll until the section is at the beginning of the viewport like this.

[image: Section without header]

But as you can remember your site has a sticky header on the top. So that space needs to reserve by remove that from the section's top.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function (event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            $("html, body").animate(
                {
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 109, // section's top - header's height
                },
                800,
                function () {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need further support.